# mat-paginator length is not working.Not able to set it

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material, angular9, mat-pagination

> I am trying to call API on the click of pagination. Initially, I had
> set the length statically and it was working fine. I was able to do a
> pagination API call.And then I had tried to set the length dynamically
> as well and it worked too, but later on, it stopped working. Please
> help me to point out my mistake.
> I am setting the length of content in this.totalEmp and able to print it on html side as well but when I am trying to set in
> mat-paginator for [length]. It is not working for me.I tried to set
> #paginator in mat-paginator as well but no change was seen.

```
Below is my implementation



**HTML:**
<mat-paginator 
    [length]="totalEmp"
    [hidden]="normalPagination"
    [pageSize]="2" 
    [pageSizeOptions]="[2]"
    [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
    (page)="pageEvent = getDataByPagination($event)"></mat-paginator>

**.ts file Code**

export class EmpComponent implements OnInit {
 
         dataSource: any;
         totalEmp: number=0;
         normalPagination: boolean;
        
        @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
         @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
        
        ngOnInit() {
            this.getTableContentCount();
          }
        
        
         getTableContentCount() {
            this.myService.CountService().subscribe(
              (response: any) => {
                if (response) {
           
                  this.totalEmp = response;
                  this.getServerData(0,this.totalEmp);
                }
              },
              (error: any) => { }
            );
          }
        
        public getDataByPagination(event?: PageEvent) {
    this.myService.getPaginationService(event).subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response) {
          this.showLoader=true;
          this.normalPagination=false;
          this.total = this.totalEmp;      
          this.allData=response;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allData);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.showLoader=false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        // handle error
      }
    );
    return event;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

> **Error:** You're initializing these below lines in every request.

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

> **Solution:** Initialize these lines only once either by placing some condition or in `ngAfterViewInit` method as per your best need.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason,i had reliased it later.Btw thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark this as answer, if you think this can help the future readers.

Answer (score 3):

use `@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { read: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;`
to make paginator work

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-12-server-side-table-pagination-example/#comment-23556